# CORS error with the Access-Controll-Allow-Origin * - NodeJS and Angular

Tags: node.js, angular, mongodb, express

I'm doing a web app with Angular and when I connect the backend with the front it gives me a CORS error:
 `Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:3700/api/save-project' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.`

I know what the CORS is but I don't know why this error because in my app.js in the backend I have the code for blocking CORS

How can I fix this issue?

Code:

app.js
    'use strict'

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var app = express();

// cargar archivo Rutas
var routes = require('./routes/product');

// Middlewares
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:false}));
app.use(bodyParser.json()); // Content-Type: image/jpg

// Configurar cabeceras y cors
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Authorization, X-API-KEY, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Access-Control-Allow-Request-Method');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE');
    res.header('Allow', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE');
    next();
});

// Rutas
app.use('/api', routes);

// exportar
module.exports = app;
```

component in Angular:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ProductService } from 'src/app/services/products.service';
import { Product } from 'src/app/models/product';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'crear',
  templateUrl: './create.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./create.component.css'],
  providers: [HttpClient, ProductService]
})
export class CreateComponent implements OnInit {
  public producto: Product;
  public product: any;

   constructor(
    //,
    //private http: HttpClient
    private _productService: ProductService
  ) { 
    this.producto = new Product('','','','',2,2);
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  onSubmit(form){
    this._productService.saveProduct(this.producto).subscribe(
      response => {
        if(response.producto){

          form.reset();

          this.product = this.producto._id;
        }else{
        alert("No se ha podido");
      };
      } 
    )
  }

}
```

Service:

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Product } from '../models/product';
import { Global } from './global.service';

@Injectable()
export class ProductService{
    public url: String;

    constructor(
        private _http: HttpClient
    ){
        this.url = Global.url;
    }

    saveProduct(product: Product): Observable<any>{
        var params = JSON.stringify(product);
        let headers =  new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/json');

        return this._http.post(this.url+'save-project', params, {headers: headers});
    }
}
```

Thanks for all

Comment: USE Express CORS Package

Comment: Thank, but there is other error `Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`

Answer (score 2):

Install **cors middleware** in your backend project:

```
npm install cors --save
```

Then, in app.js, import cors package and use it:

```
var cors = require('cors');

var app = express();

app.use(cors());
```

It's important to apply the cors middleware **BEFORE any route declaration.**

More info about cors middleware: https://github.com/expressjs/cors#readme

More info about cors: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS

Answer (score 1):

You can use cors (https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors) to handle cors settings. Please follow the usage from documentation.
If you do not want to enable cors origin and you need to get this working only for local development, you can try launching chrome with --disable-web-security mode.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add these if statement after set the CORS headers in app.js
(I needed this in graphQL and hopefully, it works!)

```
if (req.method === "OPTIONS") {
    res.send(200);
  }
```

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Authorization, X-API-KEY, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Access-Control-Allow-Request-Method');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE');
    res.header('Allow', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE');
  if (req.method === "OPTIONS") {
    res.send(200);
  }
    next();
});
```